# Bindlisten failed when starting Accept Thread

Tags: android, bluetooth, htc-hero

Can anyone tell me what this problem is? I'm trying to get my application to start an `Accept Thread`, however this error keeps occurring.

Can anyone help?

I'm using HTC Hero with Android 2.1.

```
ERROR/BluetoothChatService(9585): java.io.IOException: Bindlisten failed

android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(BluetoothAdapter.java:749)
```

According to [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.UUID%29)

```
public BluetoothServerSocket listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord (String name, UUID uuid)

Throws IOException  on error, for example Bluetooth not available, or insufficient permissions, or channel in use.
```

Some code here:
I have used `BluetoothChat.java` as a guidance and reference for developing the following code. So once Bluetooth has been enabled, the user will pressed the menu button, three buttons will then appear. The user selects `server` button if they want to start the Accept Thread and become the host of the game.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Intent serverIntent = null;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.scan:
        // Launch the DeviceListActivity to see devices and do scan
        serverIntent = new Intent(this, DeviceListActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(serverIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE);
        return true;
    case R.id.discoverable:
        // Ensure this device is discoverable by others
        ensureDiscoverable();
        return true;
    case R.id.server:
        // Ensure this device is discoverable by others
        if (mGameService != null)
        {
            // Only if the state is STATE_NONE, do we know that we haven't started already
            if (mGameService.getState() == BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE)
            {
              // Start the Bluetooth chat services
              mGameService.start();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Once the user selects the `Server` button, it will call the following method from another class:

```
    public synchronized void start() {
    if (D) Log.d(TAG, "start");

    // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
    if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

    setState(STATE_LISTEN);

    // Start the thread to listen on a BluetoothServerSocket
    if (mSecureAcceptThread == null) {
        mSecureAcceptThread = new AcceptThread();
        mSecureAcceptThread.start();
    }
}
```

And then this is the `Accept Thread`. Using Debugger, I can confirm that the `Accept Thread` is executed. However it fails at the first `try catch`, it never executes this

```
 tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME,MY_UUID);
```

**Accept thread below:**

```
private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
    // The local server socket
    private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

    public AcceptThread() {
        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;

        // Create a new list ening server socket
        try {
                tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME,MY_UUID);
            }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + "listen() failed", e);
        }
        mmServerSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "Socket Type: " +
                "BEGIN mAcceptThread" + this);
        setName("AcceptThread");

        BluetoothSocket socket = null;

        // Listen to the server socket if we're not connected
        while (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) {
            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + "accept() failed", e);
                break;
            }

            // If a connection was accepted
            if (socket != null) {
                synchronized (BluetoothChatService.this) {
                    switch (mState) {
                    case STATE_LISTEN:
                    case STATE_CONNECTING:
                        // Situation normal. Start the connected thread.
                        connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice());
                        break;
                    case STATE_NONE:
                    case STATE_CONNECTED:
                        // Either not ready or already connected. Terminate new socket.
                        try {
                            socket.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Could not close unwanted socket", e);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (D) Log.i(TAG, "END mAcceptThread, socket Type: ");

    }
```

I just did some debugging, and the following errors occurred in the `Accept Thread`. At the `socket = mmServerSocket.accept();` line.

```
[2011-05-27 13:52:21 - DeviceMonitor]Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[2011-05-27 13:52:21 - Logcat]An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:395)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:284)
    at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogPanel$3.run(LogPanel.java:527)

[2011-05-27 13:52:23 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 1
[2011-05-27 13:52:25 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 2
[2011-05-27 13:52:27 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 3
[2011-05-27 14:33:48 - Device]Error during Sync: timeout.
[2011-05-27 16:49:43 - ddms]null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:572)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHELO(HandleHello.java:142)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHelloCommands(HandleHello.java:65)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.getJdwpPacket(Client.java:671)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:317)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)

[2011-05-27 16:49:43 - ddms]null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:572)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHELO(HandleHello.java:142)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHelloCommands(HandleHello.java:65)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.getJdwpPacket(Client.java:671)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:317)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)
```

Comment: Some code has been added

Comment: I found another Question that was on Stack Overflow but was taken down. This guy had the same issue I am having. [Question Link](http://www.androidportal.info/q23716/Bindlisten-Failed-Exception-while-connecting-two-android-device)

The answer asked if he created the `RFCOMM` socket first, however isn't the `RFCOMM` socket created by the client, and not by the server device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will not work for the HTC Hero. 
I have tested it on other devices like Samsung, and found that the same error does not occur.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a [general complaint](http://community.htc.com/na/htc-forums/android/f/91/p/2336/8570.aspx) that Bluetooth wasn't implemented right with the HTC Hero. There is a complete solution available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8273159/544198).