# Bluetooth issues on HTC hero

Tags: android, bluetooth, htc-hero

I've written an android application getting data from external sensors using Bluetooth. It's working fine on Sony Ericsson XPERIA but not on a HTC Hero (it finds external devices but it can't get any data from them) I'm wondering why. After some research on the net, I still haven't found any clue.
Anyone had similar bluetooth issues on HTC?

Comment: What API level is your Hero running at?

Comment: Thanks for your response.
This HTC runs Android 2.1 so it is API level of 7.
I suppose I need to upgrate the platform. right?

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly the HTC phones had or [have] an issue at a certain API level (maybe 2.1 and below?). The resolution is reflection.

**Reference**

[Disconnect a bluetooth socket in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031796/disconnect-a-bluetooth-socket-in-android)

[Service discovery failed exception using Bluetooth on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397071/android-bluetooth-service-discovery-failed-exception)

**Solution**

Instead of using

```
tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
```

use

```
Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);
```

to get your BluetoothSocket on certain HTC phones using a certain API level.

**Solution Expanded**

I recently had an application where I had to account for this, and I did not like using this on non-HTC phones, so I had a conditional to check for HTC, if true then use reflection, otherwise dont.

```
public BTConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {

    mmDevice = device;
    BluetoothSocket tmp = null;

    // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the given BluetoothDevice
    if (isAnHTCDevice()) 
    {
        try 
        {
            Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
            tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, Integer.valueOf(1));
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Log.e(BCTAG, "Error at HTC/createRfcommSocket: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage(MSG_BT_LOG_MESSAGE, "Exception creating htc socket: " + e));
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        try 
        {
            UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Log.e(BCTAG, "Error at createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage(MSG_BT_LOG_MESSAGE, "Exception creating socket: " + e));
        }
    }

    mmSocket = tmp;
}
```

isAnHTCDevice():

```
public boolean isAnHTCDevice()
{
    String manufacturer = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
    if (manufacturer.toLowerCase().contains("htc"))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Jack,
Unfortunately I still can't open a socket connection, the code stuck on that part: tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);

reflexion is obviously not working but I will upgrade the phone from 2.1 to the latest version.
I'll keep you inform if it works.

Comment: Maybe the '1' should be called as Integet.valueOf(1). Are you sure you want RFComm port 1?

Answer (score 2):

you can make it like this:

```
private final String PBAP_UUID = "0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"; //standard pbap uuid            
mSocket = mDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(ParcelUuid.fromString(PBAP_UUID).getUuid())    
mSocket.connect();
```

Just do it.

Answer (score 1):

you can make it like this:

```
private final String PBAP_UUID = "0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"; //standard pbap uuid

mSocket = mDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(ParcelUuid.fromString(PBAP_UUID).getUuid());
```

mSocket.connect();

Just do it.